# Click once deployment with framework 3.5 (When size in Mb's matters)

Tags: visual-studio-2008, frameworks, clickonce

Currently i am publishing my app with clickonce and the V2.0 framework.

Users with no framework installed, should download the extra 20Mb of the framework.

What will happen if i decide to switch to the 3.5 framework?

Users should download first 50-60Mb's just for the framework and then install my app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just have users install with the [.Net 3.5 SP1 Bootstrapper](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=AB99342F-5D1A-413D-8319-81DA479AB0D7&displaylang=en).  It's a 2.8 MB download that figures out what bits the user needs and only downloads and installs those.  That way the download size is tailored to what each individual actually needs.